# what iOS engine will help my create "hot glowing" 3d spheres?

Tags: ios5, 3d

I want to have the 3D spheres to look like hot glowing, you know when a hot poker iron, for example, has that slight glowing look?

I've seen some recommendations of just putting a gaussian blur as a sprite...but I'm not sure that's quite what I'm looking for...so just seeing if there are other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On "normal" graphics hardware, a bloom affect is usually achieved via post-processing passes in screen space, which are typically pretty expensive on mobile GPUs.  I know that the PowerVR SDK for OpenGLES has some examples of how to do this, and they also provide an excellently detailed white paper on how they modified the traditional Bloom algorithm to achieve the effect on i-Devices.

[PowerVR Post-Processing Effects Recommendations (PDF)](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/docs/PowerVR.Post%20Processing%20Effects%20Development%20Recommendations.1.7f.External.pdf)

[PowerVR OpenGLES SDK Download Site](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES2xSGX.asp)

IIRC, I think you'll need to register (it's free) as a developer before downloading the SDK.

Comment: thanks --- is there a 'hack' you recommend that wouldn't use as much post-processing power?